# Formula for Bifilar Pendulum

Tags: oscillators, moment-of-inertia

What is the formula for a Bifilar Pendulum's Period? Assuming the Pendulum oscillates sideways. ( Spins to the left and then to the right etc. ). I can't seem to find the formula online.

Comment: Not that hard to find by Goggling [bifilar pendulum period](https://physlab.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Bifilar-Pendulum-1.compressed.pdf)?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\omega ^2 = \frac{mgab}{Il}
$$
where m is the mass of pendulum, a is the half of the distance between hanging points attached to the ceiling, b is the half of the distance between hanging points attached to the body, I is moment of inertia of the body, l is distance between ceiling and center of mass